# radius in D3 is being drawn bigger than it should

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm building a bubble map using `D`3, but the radius of the bubbles are **bigger** than they should be doing the operation outside of `D3`. I'm sure is just something simple I'm missing as it is my first bubble map in `D3`, but I can't find what it is.

This is the code I add for the `radius attribute` when drawing each bubble:

```
.attr("r", function(d) { 
     return radius(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(10, (1.5*d.properties.mag)+4.35)/10000000000000)/Math.PI)); 
  });
```

For a `d.properties.mag` of 8.3, the resultant bubble rendered is:

```
<circle id="t1442444072620" transform="translate(244.5523934369255,434.147524023737)"
        r="68.38953170695866" class="selected">
 </circle>
```

As you see, `radius` is **68.4px**. But that same operation changing `d.properties.mag` for 8.3

```
console.log(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(10, (1.5*8.3)+4.35)/10000000000000)/Math.PI))
```

Gives me a result of a `radius` of **44 px**. The problem is not getting the right number on `d.properties.mag`, I checked that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check d.properties.mag valeu is correct when you run it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Already checked, and that's not the issue

Comment: What's the `radius()` function?

Comment: Ok, sorry for having bothered you all, it was a problem with domain/range...